# Google Cloud messaging with java EE

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Is there any good tutorial with well documented code regarding google cloud messaging using Java EE like this one..

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

using php.
I am making chat application using websockets in android.
I have a working code for android to websocket endpoint class interaction. The only problem is how to use GCM in current enviroment.

Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the best GCM tutorial ever:

http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

**PHP Server code:**

```
    <?php
        //generic php function to send GCM push notification
       function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
            //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
            $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
            $fields = array(
                'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
                'data' => $message,
            );
            // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
            define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyDA5dlLInMWVsJEUTIHV0u7maB82MCsZbU");        
            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);   
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);               
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }
    ?>
    <?php

        //this block is to post message to GCM on-click
        $pushStatus = "";   
        if(!empty($_GET["push"])) { 
            $gcmRegID  = file_get_contents("GCMRegId.txt");
            $pushMessage = $_POST["message"];   
            if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {      
                $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
                $message = array("m" => $pushMessage);  
                $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
            }       
        }

        //this block is to receive the GCM regId from external (mobile apps)
        if(!empty($_GET["shareRegId"])) {
            $gcmRegID  = $_POST["regId"]; 
            file_put_contents("GCMRegId.txt",$gcmRegID);
            echo "Ok!";
            exit;
        }   
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</h1> 
            <form method="post" action="gcm.php/?push=1">                                                
                <div>                                
                    <textarea rows="2" name="message" cols="23" placeholder="Message to transmit via GCM"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div><input type="submit"  value="Send Push Notification via GCM" /></div>
            </form>
            <p><h3><?php echo $pushStatus; ?></h3></p>        
        </body>
    </html>
```

Or Java server:

**index.jsp:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <%
        String pushStatus = "";
        Object pushStatusObj = request.getAttribute("pushStatus");

        if (pushStatusObj != null) {
            pushStatus = pushStatusObj.toString();
        }
    %>
    <head>
    <title>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Server in Java</h1>

        <form action="GCMNotification" method="post">

            <div>
                <textarea rows="2" name="message" cols="23"
                    placeholder="Message to transmit via GCM"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Push Notification via GCM" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <p>
            <h3>
                <%=pushStatus%>
            </h3>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**GCMNotification.java:**

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
    import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

    @WebServlet("/GCMNotification")
    public class GCMNotification extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        // Put your Google API Server Key here
        private static final String GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY = "AIzaSyDA5dlLInMWVsJEUTIHV0u7maB82MCsZbU";
        static final String MESSAGE_KEY = "message";    

        public GCMNotification() {
            super();
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(request, response);

        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


            Result result = null;

            String share = request.getParameter("shareRegId");

            // GCM RedgId of Android device to send push notification
            String regId = "";
            if (share != null && !share.isEmpty()) {
                regId = request.getParameter("regId");
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("GCMRegId.txt");
                writer.println(regId);
                writer.close();
                request.setAttribute("pushStatus", "GCM RegId Received.");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
                        .forward(request, response);
            } else {

                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                            "GCMRegId.txt"));
                    regId = br.readLine();
                    br.close();
                    String userMessage = request.getParameter("message");
                    Sender sender = new Sender(GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
                    Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30)
                            .delayWhileIdle(true).addData(MESSAGE_KEY, userMessage).build();
                    System.out.println("regId: " + regId);
                    result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus", result.toString());
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus",
                            "RegId required: " + ioe.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    request.setAttribute("pushStatus", e.toString());
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")
                        .forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
```

For GCM on **device side** these thing are required:

1. Google Play Services in SDK
2. Google APIs
3. Google Play Services Lib project as Android dependency
4. Google Project Id

In **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="yourPkgName"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="yourPkgName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="yourPkgName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    ...
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="yourPkgName" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**GCMNotificationIntentService.java:**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG,
                            "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                    + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }

                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server: "
                        + extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
    }
}
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

So now you just need to call **registerInBackground()** method and send regId to your server:

```
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regId = gcm.register(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                            + regId);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;
                    //Save in preferences and send to your server
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
                }
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Registered with GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Example of sending regId to server:

```
    public String shareRegIdWithAppServer(final Context context, final String regId) {

        String result = "";
        Map paramsMap = new HashMap();
        paramsMap.put("regId", regId);
        try {
            URL serverUrl = null;
            try {
                serverUrl = new URL(Config.APP_SERVER_URL);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("AppUtil", "URL Connection Error: " + Config.APP_SERVER_URL, e);
                result = "Invalid URL: " + Config.APP_SERVER_URL;
            }
            StringBuilder postBody = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator> iterator = paramsMap.entrySet().iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Entry param = iterator.next();
                postBody.append(param.getKey()).append('=').append(param.getValue());
                if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    postBody.append('&');
                }
            }
            String body = postBody.toString();
            byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;
            try {
                httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
                httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
                httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
                httpCon.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
                httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();
                int status = httpCon.getResponseCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    result = "RegId shared with Application Server. RegId: " + regId;
                } else {
                    result = "Post Failure." + " Status: " + status;
                }
            } finally {
                if (httpCon != null) {
                    httpCon.disconnect();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = "Post Failure. Error in sharing with App Server.";
            Log.e("AppUtil", "Error in sharing with App Server: " + e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Link only answers are not good for this site, you could have used the comment feature instead. Please improve your answer and add the relevant code details. Link might be outdated at some time in future.

Comment: I can't use comment feature in questions. My reputation is less than 50.